# Using forfiles with a command-line program

Tags: image, loops, image-processing, cmd, converters

I have an image debayering program that I run through command prompt.  It can debayer individual images with this command:

```
DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -GPU -pattern GRBG -i inputfilename.pgm -o outputfilename.ppm
```

I'm trying to get it to run on an entire directory of .pgm files, and I discovered the forfiles command.

I've been trying something like:

`forfiles /M *.pgm /C "DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -GPU -pattern GRBG -i @fname.pgm -o @fname.ppm`"

but the debayering program just returns its help window when I run that.
I have success looping the debayer program if the files are named the same with increasing numbers, then I can use this for loop:

```
for %a in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1
2 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
39) do DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -CPU -pattern GRBG -i single%a.pgm -o si
ngle%a.ppm
```

and that works, but as of now, forfiles doesn't.  I suspect it has something to do with the program not accepting the @fname from forfiles.  Any thoughts for how to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figued it out!

I tried using hex escape characters (0x22) but that didn't work. Neither did % escapes.

So, I made a mini for-loop and put @fname as a string.

```
forfiles /M *.pgm /C "cmd /c for %s in (@fname) do DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -CPU -pattern GRBG -i %s.pgm -o %s.ppm"
```